# Swift 2 Playground(Xcode 7 Beta 4) - Multiple types in an array only work when UIKit imported?

Tags: swift2, xcode7-beta4

I was trying out Swift arrays in the Playground, when I noticed this peculiar behaviour

The below code works fine.

```
import UIKit

var array = [1,2,3,"Booyaa"]
```

But, as soon as I **remove the "import UIKit" line from the Playground**, I get the following error

> Playground execution failed: /var/folders/tx/tvyf1r314wj9371f491qx8wjbqbgsr/T/./lldb/11708/playground71.swift:2:17: error: 'Int' is not convertible to 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'
>   var array = [1, 2, 3, "Booyaa"]

Why does this happen?

Comment: swift2 is pain in the arse, boy!

Comment: No, no need. It's need `import Foundation`.

Comment: @longpham Could you please explain in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is here, in response to an identical question I posted on the Apple Dev forums => https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/35389

> It's because Swift Arrays can only contain objects that are the same
>   type. Your array has integers and a string. When you import UIKit the
>   objects in the array become objects of type NSObject by virtue of
>   Swift's inference engine. To see for yourself, add the line after the
>   array definition, you'll see the type as Swift.array

```
import UIKit  
var array = [1,2,3,"Swift2"]  
array.dynamicType
```

Answer (score 0):

With high programming language this need a `lexical structure` for checking and compare complex type as your question. And it's implemented in `Foundation` framework.

Also `UIKit` implemented some `UI` api as `UIView`, etc... And in `UIKit` framework it's need using `Foundation` framework.

BTW: `Foundation` framework is core `Swift`, `Objective-C` language.

Hope this helps!